# arduino pro mini fqbn

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

## Introduction

I am trying to program an arduino pro mini, I have to use this board because of it's size.
I use the arduino-cli to program arduino and one of the steps to upload code to the system requires the board's fqbn and I can't find it anywhere.

## Question

Does anybody know this board's fqbn (fully-qualified board name)?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.6.21/boards.txt#L670-#L697